# GINA availability on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista

I would like to know information about GINA.

I am aware that this is a part of Windows XP.

Is it present in Windows 7?

Does GINA based client works with Win 7?

I would appreciate if some one help with this.

Comment: GINA is replaced since Vista: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication#Recent_Windows_versions

Comment: Hi magicandre1981,

Thank you for reply.

The Wikipedia link answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

[Since Windows Vista, GINA has been entirely replaced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication#Recent_Windows_versions) by [Credential Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which allow for significantly increased flexibility in supporting multiple credential collection methods.

So Windows 7 doesn't support GINA any longer.